# Errors when porting Testing Library React tests from Create react App to Vitest

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vite, testing-library, vitest

I'm having issues moving react testing lib tests from create react app to vite:

```
src/Pages/WelcomePage/views/SelectUser/index.test.jsx [ src/Pages/WelcomePage/views/SelectUser/index.test.jsx ]
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'
Require stack:
- /Users/nikos/WebstormPro.../node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+react@13.3.0_react-dom@17.0.2+react@17.0.2/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js
 ❯ Object.<anonymous> node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+react@13.3.0_react-dom@17.0.2+react@17.0.2/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:35:46
```

Current libs in white

[image]

edit -------------- upgrading to

```
  "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
```

fixed the above but now I get:

```
 ❯ resetClipboardStubOnView node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+user-event@14.2.1_@testing-library+dom@8.16.0/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/index.mjs:320:30
    318| }
    319| function resetClipboardStubOnView(window) {
    320|   if (isClipboardStub(window.navigator.clipboard)) {
       |                              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the following in the vite config

```
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "happy-dom", // or 'jsdom', 'node'

  },
```

If you get error `Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'`

Upgrade to React 18 and tell your clients you are dumping ie11.